# Replacement for message_to_tf in noetic

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[message_to_tf](http://wiki.ros.org/message_to_tf) is no longer available in noetic. What's a good replacement for it?

Context, if helpful: I'm using this package in simulation to test with perfect localization, which I accomplish by publishing Gazebo's `/exact_pose` to the TF tree.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/364807/replacement-for-message_to_tf-in-noetic/) by [chfritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/25700/chfritz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 553 on 2020-11-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chfritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/25700/chfritz/) on 2020-11-04**:
One thought was to use `robot_localization`, but is there a simpler replacement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I'm using this package in simulation to test with perfect localization, which I accomplish by publishing Gazebo's `/exact_pose` to the TF tree.

If I understand you correctly, I'd suggest to use [fake_localization](https://wiki.ros.org/fake_localization) for this.

It'll pretend to be an actual localisation component, but still "just forward" the ground truth coming from the simulator.

---

Edit: and if you'd really like to use `message_to_tf`, why not build it from source? I haven't tried, but it doesn't appear to have any really crazy dependencies, just standard packages.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1